# How to hide elements when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having a bit of difficulty getting this jquery to work. I have a form where all fields are nested in a `div.form-group`. The subscribe button has an id of `subscribe`.

I want the form fields to disappear on click... but my js is not working out. Here's what I've tried, to no avail:

```
(function($) {
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#subscribe").click(function() {
            $(".form-group").css("display: none");
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The `form-group` class is set to `display: block` in the CSS.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

cheers,

Comment: Will you show the part of your markup that is affected by the JavaScript?

Comment: Typo mistake.. `$(".form-group").css("display" ,"none");`

Comment: Or `.css({"display": "none"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides a `.hide()` method as a shortcut to setting the various CSS directives that hide an element (`display: none` and `visibility: hidden`, for example).

```
$(".form-group").hide();
```

If you prefer to set the CSS directly, place quotes around both elements of the statement:

```
$(".form-group").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Thanks  `.hide` is good one to know. The rest helps me understand the `.css` method too!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".form-group").css("display: none");
```

supposed to be

```
$(".form-group").css("display", "none");

                 **OR**
$(".form-group").css({ "display" : "none"});
```

you have been trying to set the attribute as a `single string`.
It is supposed to be comma separated if it's only a single attribute that you want to change.

Or an object if you want to target multiple css properties at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#anotherid" ).on('click', function() {
        $( "#idhere" ).hide('slow');
    });
```

Try this

Comment: Since the question included the id and classes, I'd recommend to include those in your answer. As it is now, it almost looks like you just copied and pasted this from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#subscribe").click(function() {
                $(".form-group").hide()
            });
}
```